# add value to classes and subclasses with c#

Tags: c#, xml, class

I have the following code of my class,

```
public class ClassGPS
{
    [XmlElement("head")]
    public Head head;
    [XmlElement("events")]
    public Events events;


    public class Head
    {
        [XmlAttribute("nemo")]
        public string Nemo { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("dte")]
        public string Dte { get; set; }

    }


    public class Events
    {

        [XmlElement("event")]
        public _EVENT events;

    }

    public class _EVENT
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("desc")]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("gps")]
        public _GPS gps;
        [XmlElement("mov")]
        public _MOV mov;
        [XmlElement("geo")]
        public _GEO geo;
        [XmlElement("passengers")]
        public _PASSENGERS passengers;
        [XmlElement("sensors")]
        public _SENSORS sensors;
    }


    public class _GPS
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("dte")]
        public string Dte { get; set; }
    }

    public class _MOV
    {
        [XmlAttribute("plate")]
        public string Plate { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("vel")]
        public string Vel { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("odo")]
        public string Odo { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("rpm")]
        public string Rpm { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("rutDri")]
        public string Rutdri { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("tipDri")]
        public string Tipdri { get; set; }
    }

    public class _GEO
    {
        [XmlAttribute("lat")]
        public string Lat { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("long")]
        public string Long { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("alt")]
        public string Alt { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("dir")]
        public string Dir { get; set; }

    }

    public class _PASSENGERS
    {
        [XmlElement("pass")]
        public _PASS pass;
    }


    public class _PASS
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("rut")]
        public string Rut { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("tip")]
        public string Tip { get; set; }
    }

    public class _SENSORS
    {
        [XmlElement("sensor")]
        public _SENSOR sensor;
    }



    public class _SENSOR
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("unit")]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

}
```

and use the code below to fill

```
 public ClassGPS esb()
    {

        List<ClassGPS._EVENT> listevent = new List<ClassGPS._EVENT>();
        List<ClassGPS._PASSENGERS> listpassegers = new List<ClassGPS._PASSENGERS>();
        List<ClassGPS._SENSORS> listsensors = new List<ClassGPS._SENSORS>();

        ClassGPS gps = new ClassGPS
        {
            head = new ClassGPS.Head { Nemo = "XYS-XML", Dte = "2012-02-02 15:05:05.456" },              
              events = new ClassGPS.Events
                {

                for (int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++)   {

                    listevent.Add (new ClassGPS._EVENT
                        {
                            Type = "PPT",
                            Desc = "position_time",
                            gps = new ClassGPS._GPS { Id = i, Dte = "2012-02-02 15:05:05.456" },
                            mov = new ClassGPS._MOV { Plate = "111456-2", Vel = "98", Odo = "45678987", Rpm = "465489", Rutdri = "13649654", Tipdri = "23133216" },
                            geo = new ClassGPS._GEO { Lat = "-34.324", Long = "70.366", Alt = "32.506", Dir = "86.32123" },


                                passengers = new ClassGPS._PASSENGERS
                                {
                                    for (int x = 1; x <= 9 ; x++)   {
                                        listpassegers.Add ( new ClassGPS._PASS { 
                                          Id = x, 
                                          Rut = "2132132", 
                                          Tip = "121325646" })
                                    }

                                },


                                sensors = new ClassGPS._SENSORS
                            {

                                 for (int y = 1; x <= 3 ; x++)   {

                                    listsensors.Add ( new ClassGPS._SENSOR { 
                                        Type ="LS", 
                                        Id = y, 
                                        Unit= "%" , 
                                        Value="21" })
                                 }
                            }

                        })

                }


                }

        };

        return gps;
    }
```

I cannot fill with the code because I don't know how.
I need the following result.

```
 <ClassGPS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <head nemo="XYS-XML" dte="2012-02-02 15:05:05.456" /> 
  <events>
      <event type="PPT" desc="position_time">
      <gps id="213212315646" dte="2012-02-02 15:05:05.456" /> 
      <mov plate="111456-2" vel="98" odo="45678987" rpm="465489" rutDri="13649654" tipDri="23133216" /> 
      <geo lat="-34.324" long="70.366" alt="32.506" dir="86.32123" /> 
          <passengers>
              <pass id="1" rut="2132132" tip="121325646" /> 
          </passengers>
          <sensors>
                <sensor type="LS" id="1" unit="%" value="21" /> 
                <sensor type="LS" id="1" unit="%" value="21" /> 
          </sensors>
      </event>
      <event type="PPT" desc="position_time">
          <gps id="213212315646" dte="2012-02-02 15:05:05.456" /> 
          <mov plate="111456-2" vel="98" odo="45678987" rpm="465489" rutDri="13649654" tipDri="23133216" /> 
          <geo lat="-34.324" long="70.366" alt="32.506" dir="86.32123" /> 
          <passengers>
                     <pass id="1" rut="2132132" tip="121325646" /> 
                     <pass id="2" rut="2132546132" tip="1213256546" /> 
          </passengers>
          <sensors>
                <sensor type="LS" id="1" unit="%" value="21" /> 
          </sensors>
      </event>
  </events>
```

The passengers, sensors and events can be more than one.

Comment: Please describe what the problem is.

Comment: your code looks to be  using xml serialization, and the second snippet populates said class instances. you need to use xmlSerailizer class.

Comment: @NathanTregillus apology but as I can do that with my code. not much about xml and classes

Comment: @NathanOliver the problem is that I need to insert more than one event to the list with a for loop and don't do it and this is not result. example Passengers = new ClassGPS._PASSENGERS { for (int x = 1; x <= 9; x ++) { listpassegers.Add (new ClassGPS._PASS { Id = x, Ruth = "2132132" Tip = "121325646"}) } },..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified and shortened your code slightly.

```
public class Gps
{
    [XmlElement("head")]
    public HeadData Head { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("events")]
    [XmlArrayItem("event")]
    public List<EventData> Events { get; set; }

    public class HeadData
    {
        [XmlAttribute("nemo")]
        public string Nemo { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("dte")]
        public DateTime Dte { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventData
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("desc")]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("gps")]
        public GpsData Gps { get; set; }
    }

    public class GpsData
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("dte")]
        public DateTime Dte { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Populate data and serialize

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var eventData = new List<Gps.EventData>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        eventData.Add(new Gps.EventData
        {
            Desc = "X", 
            Type = "Y",
            Gps = new Gps.GpsData
            {
                Dte = DateTime.Now,
                Id = i.ToString()
            }
        });
    }

    Gps gps = new Gps()
    {
        Head = new Gps.HeadData {Dte = DateTime.Now, Nemo = "XYS-XML"},
        Events = eventData
    };


    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(gps.GetType());
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\gps.xml"))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, gps);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

XML result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Gps xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <head nemo="XYS-XML" dte="2015-04-27T18:48:47.9499022+02:00" />
  <events>
    <event type="Y" desc="X">
      <gps id="0" dte="2015-04-27T18:48:47.9489022+02:00" />
    </event>
    <event type="Y" desc="X">
      <gps id="1" dte="2015-04-27T18:48:47.9499022+02:00" />
    </event>
    <event type="Y" desc="X">
      <gps id="2" dte="2015-04-27T18:48:47.9499022+02:00" />
    </event>
    <event type="Y" desc="X">
      <gps id="3" dte="2015-04-27T18:48:47.9499022+02:00" />
    </event>
    <event type="Y" desc="X">
      <gps id="4" dte="2015-04-27T18:48:47.9499022+02:00" />
    </event>
  </events>
</Gps>
```